# use htaccess file to prevent link to specific external site?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a social network using a popular php framework. MY competition is trying to spam my site with links to his site. IS there a way to use htaccess to prevent links leading to his site? have www.his_domain.com clicks lead to google or right back to my home page?

Comment: I think you're talking about links /from/ your site leading to his site, which users of your site (possibly him/his agents) have put there?

If so, .htaccess is not going to help you.

Comment: yes, I want to block outgoing traffic to a specific site.  This can't be done with .htaccess ? why won't this work?

Comment: No.  .htaccess is to filter traffic coming into your site (hence, access).   "Outgoing" traffic is between the client web browser and the destination endpoint only and does not ordinarily even flow through your servers.

Comment: yeah that makes sense. I was for some reason thinking the webserver could see any links being posted and rewrite them but that would probably be a php thing now that I think of it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RewriteCond](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteCond) and [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) to create rules

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} his_domain.com

RewriteRule google.com

but preventing a user from navigating to external sites many not work as BadZen said. You can try preventing the spam instead

Comment: that code caused an internal server error 500. Is there a fix for this?